# How to change per-plugin codec in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails3

While I understand that it is not "best practice", I have a lot of legacy plugins that I am upgrading to Grails 3, and I need to set their GSP encoding back to the old default of "none" (because everything is already encoded where it needs to be, and we expect non-encoded data elsewhere.)  Unfortunately, this appears to not work per the documentation.

The Grails 3.2.11 docs say:

> Per Plugin Encoding
>
> Grails also features the ability to control the codecs used on a per plugin basis. For example if you have a plugin named foo installed, then placing the following configuration in your application.groovy will disable encoding for only the foo plugin
>
> foo.grails.views.gsp.codecs.expression = "none"

This did not work, using Grails 3.2.11.  Encoding is still "html".

Other things I tried, that also did not work:

- Just changing the plugin's application.yml from the default values (this seems like it would be ideal to me, and was what I originally expected would control the plugin encoding)
- Same line, in runtime.groovy
- Same line, in the plugin's plugin.groovy
- Same concept with the prefix, in both the application's and the plugin's application.yml
- Changes per suggestions in [How can I exclude a plugin from grails default gsp encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785413/how-can-i-exclude-a-plugin-from-grails-default-gsp-encoding)

I'm perfectly willing to write this up as a Grails bug, but figured I would ask here first in case somebody else has already solved this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Opened https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10722 today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See linked grails issue for answer; short version is that:

- all codecs must be valid, or defaults are used due to exception thrown in codec processing
- plugins should be cleaned before publishing, or precompiled gsps may still use previous codecs